# Bind Combobox to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to get comfortable again with C# so I decided to start with an "easy" one. I would like create a dictionary from a XML file and bind it to a combobox. These are my snippets:

XML

```
<configuration>
    <Paths>
        <add key="Path_DQM_CE_Prod" value="DQM-CE\DQM_CE_12.2.0_17615\QMConfigurationEditor.exe" />
        <add key="Path_DQM_CE_Test" value="DQM-CE\QMConfigurationEditor.exe" />
    </Paths>
</configuration>
```

Code-behind (works, I an iterate through the dictionary)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    ///read XML and store into dictionary
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"\\ServerXYZ\Settings_CAX_Startcenter\config.xml");

    var Paths = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Paths").Elements()
                       .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"),
                                     a => (string)a.Attribute("value"));
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.Key" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Pretty sure my binding is wrong but Im unable to solve it

Comment: var Paths - is a local variable. Binding works with Property. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-how-to-topics?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210210/binding-combobox-items-to-dictionary-of-enums?rq=1

Comment: @Maxim thank you for your links, especially the first one will help me to get more comfortable with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paths` must be a *public property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    ///read XML and store into dictionary
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"\\ServerXYZ\Settings_CAX_Startcenter\config.xml");

    Paths = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Paths").Elements()
                       .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"),
                                     a => (string)a.Attribute("value"));
}

public Dictionary<string, string> Paths { get; }
```

You would then set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the property of the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` that you want to display in the `ComboBox`, i.e. "Key" or "Value":

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Comment: thank you! exactly what I was looking for. Need to get back to the roots, almost forgot everything -.-